# Converting n length two dimensional array to n level nested object

Tags: javascript

I have two dimensional array like below

```
var testData = [
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 109], // goes to level-n
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 25],  // goes to level-n
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 20],  // goes to level-n
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 17],  // goes to level-n
];
```

I need to convert it in below structure

```
var resultData = [{
  "name": "level-1",
  "sub-name": [{
    "name": "level-2",
    "sub-name": [{
      "name": "level-3",
      "val": 109
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "level-1",
  "sub-name": [{
    "name": "level-2",
    "sub-name": [{
      "name": "level-3",
      "val": 25
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "level-1",
  "sub-name": [{
    "name": "level-2",
    "sub-name": [{
      "name": "level-3",
      "val": 20
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "level-1",
  "sub-name": [{
    "name": "level-2",
    "sub-name": [{
      "name": "level-3",
      "val": 17
    }]
  }]
}];
```

I have tried the following but It is missing level-1 and showing level-3 instead of level-2.

```js
var testData = [
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 109], // goes to level-n
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 25],  // goes to level-n
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 20],  // goes to level-n
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 17],  // goes to level-n
];
var index = 3;
var testArray = [];


function converter(d) {

  d.forEach(function(b) {
    recursive(b, 0);
  });

}

function recursive(element, i, testObj) {
  testObj = testObj || {};
  testObj.name = element[i];
  testObj.category = element[i];
  testObj.subCategory = [{}];
  ++i;
  if (i < index) {
    recursive(element, i, testObj);
  }
  if (i == index) {
    testObj.subCategory[0].name = element[index - 1];
    testObj.subCategory[0].val = element[index];
    testObj.subCategory[0].subCategory = null;
    return testObj;
  }
 document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(testObj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
}
converter(testData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an iterative solution to the problem:

```js
var testData = [
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 109], // goes to level-n
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 25],  // goes to level-n
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 20],  // goes to level-n
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 17],  // goes to level-n
],
  resultData= [];

testData.forEach(function(a) {
  var obj = {};
  resultData.push(obj);

  a.forEach(function(val, idx) {
    if(idx < a.length - 2) {
      obj.name= val;
      obj['sub-name']= [{}];
      obj= obj['sub-name'][0];
    }
    else {
      obj.name= a[idx - 1];
      obj.val= val;
    }
  });
});

document.body.innerHTML= '<pre>'+JSON.stringify(resultData, null, 2)+'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
var testData = [
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 109], // goes to level-n
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 25],  // goes to level-n
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 20],  // goes to level-n
  ["level-1", "level-2", "level-3", 17],  // goes to level-n
]; 

objectify = function(vals) {
  if (vals.length <= 2) {
    return { name: vals[0], val: vals[1] }
  } else {
    var name = vals.shift()
    return { "name": name,    
             "sub-name": [objectify(vals)] }
  }
}

result = testData.map(objectify)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

(see the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/74o5gkmc/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do 2 fixes:

*Fix 1:* In your code, you assume that testObj is the inner *object* of the subcategory list. However, you pass in the entire list, not the object itself. Thinking about the *types* and *purpose* of your recursive functions' parameters will help you avoid this bug.

```
recursive(element, i, testObj.subCategory[0]);
```

*Fix 2:* To get rid of an object attribute, you need to assign `undefined` to it, not `null`.

```
testObj.subCategory[0].subCategory = undefined;
```